# Borders on overlapping transparent objects are disappearing

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I need to display a few thousand transparent objects on a figure in MATLAB, each with its border showing.  However, when I use fill to plot the objects, the borders in the interiors of the intersections are somehow covered up by the transparent objects, even if one of the objects is on top.  Here is a code sample that shows the behavior I mean:

```
t = linspace(0,2*pi,100);
s = linspace(0,2*pi,50);

eps = .35;

f = figure;
hold on;
c = [1.0 0.5 0.0];

for i = 1:1:length(s)
    x = eps*cos(t)+cos(s(i));
    y = eps*sin(t)+sin(s(i));
    fill(x,y,c,'EdgeColor','k','LineWidth',1,'facealpha',.25);
end
```

As you can see, the boundaries of the circles that are on the interior are more faint than the boundaries on the exterior. What I expect to see is a front-most circle that has a completely black border, and a back-most circle that has the most transparent border on the interior.

[image: Example]

Does anyone know how to make it so the borders are drawn as the objects are placed?  So that the borders are drawn in front of the transparent objects when they are, indeed, on top?

Comment: how about setting the edgealpha dynamically in the loop e.g.     `fill(x,y,c,'EdgeColor','k','LineWidth',1,'facealpha',.25,'edgealpha',i/length(s));` (also using `i` and `eps` as variables in Matlab is generally not recomended)

Comment: @RTL: Beat me to the punch!

Comment: I copy pasted your code and I cant reproduce this, I get a normal looking image: http://i.imgur.com/KiselwF.png (Matlab 2012a, win7 here)

Comment: I also cannot reproduce this (Matlab 2012b). What Matlab version are you using? Maybe it is too old and the bug was fixed in the meantime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the ZData after calling fill:

```
for i = 1:1:length(s)
    x = eps*cos(t)+cos(s(i));
    y = eps*sin(t)+sin(s(i));
    z = ones(size(x))*i;
    h=fill(x,y,c,'EdgeColor','k','LineWidth',1,'facealpha',.25);
    set(h,'ZData',z);
end
```

[image]